# How do I move a container to the right side of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I need to move everything from .right and below to the right side of my screen and have the image on the left. Ideally, they would be side by side, same size, etc. HTML and CSS code included below. I'm guessing this is very simple but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content,
.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}


/* Left Side */

.picture {
  background-image: url(picture.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 40vw;
}

.logo {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 20vh;
  gap: 1vw;
  padding: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.odinPic {
  height: 10vh;
}


/* Right Side */

.right {
  width: 60vw;
  background-color: rgb(243, 240, 239);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left {
  padding-left: 3vw;
}

.dummyText {
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.otherText {
  margin: 40px 0 80px;
}


/* Form */

.form {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.input {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-wrap;
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 50%;
}

.formTitle {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

input {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgb(66, 66, 66);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

button {
  background-color: #596D48;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 2px solid rgb(66, 66, 66);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.login {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #596D48;
  ;
  font-weight: 700;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="picture">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="odin.png" class="odinPic">
      <h1 class="odin">ODIN</h1>"
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="dummyText left">
    <p>This is not a real online service! You know you need someting like this in your life to help you realizer your deepest dreams.</p>
    <p>Sign up <em>now</em> to get started.</p>
    <p class="otherText">You <em>know</em> you want to.</p>
  </div>
  <form action="#">
    <div class="form left">
      <p class="formTitle">Let's do this!</p>
      <div class="input">
        <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name" required>
      </div>

      <div class="input">
        <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="last-name" id="last-name" required>
      </div>

      <div class="input">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required>
      </div>

      <div class="input">
        <label for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone-number" id="phone-number" minlength="10" maxlength="10">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left button"><button type="submit">Join</button></div>
  </form>
  <div class="login left">
    <p>Already have a member?</p><a href="#">Log In</a></div>
</div>
```

I have tried changing the containers but I would prefer to avoid using absolute positioning.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping them in a flex or grid container?

Comment: That worked! So simple, I knew it was something very obvious. Thank you for the help @drak

Answer (score 0):

position: absolute;
margin-left: 50px;